# How to run a jquery mobile webpage on Mobile phone(Android)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, openlayers

I designed a jquerymobile webpage on my laptop. The webpage consists of mobile Openlayers map with some data. It is working fine on my desktop, but I want test it on my Android phone.

I did some research on that. I came across Phonegap, which converts jquery mobile page to mobile application(any platform). But I dont want to change my page to an application, I just need to test it on my phone.

Looking forward for your suggestions.'

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: Put the code in Dropbox or some file storage and open it from there. Or, even simpler, copy the folder with your js, css, html files to your phone and open it from a file explorer on your phone.

Comment: @hungerpain Thanks for the reply. I tried that. But I am unable to see the map on phone. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try one thing; deploy it on a server I generally use Wamp its the easiest and make sure ur mobile is connected with the laptop then open your mobile browser, in place of localhost use your laptop IP it works

Comment: Thanks a lot... I installed the wamp server and was able to run the application on server. My only concern is with the mobile browser as I couldnt open. Can you please help me

Comment: connect your mobile with laptop wifi, consider if your application is hosted on www in folder [test] , then in your mobile browser open the link http://[ip address of laptop]:[port]/test.         let me know whether you got it or not.

Answer (score 0):

We use PhoneGap, jQueryMobile, [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), and [marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) at the client side.
You can also take a look at the example in [here](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette). PhoneGap is no included in this example but the example is actually part of the PhoneGap projet under the www folder.

The whole point of using PhoneGap is that it allows you to develop app using HTML5/JS related technologies at the client side, with little or no changes.

The [repro](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette) can be run as client app from desktop browser and that is how we do most of the development and testing. Then followed by putting the whole repro under phoneGap’s www folder and it will become an app.

Hope this help.